# Run Python File from server on click of html button

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have a python file on my server. I want to run this file whenever user clicks submit button. Both my files .py and .html are in different directories. And I also cant use any framework

How to do this?

Comment: use Python framework like Django, Flask, Bottle to create web page. And you need server which can run Python code - Django,Flask, Bottle - or it uses CGI to run scripts in different languages - or it can run PHP which could run Python code. Using only HTML and JavaScript you can't run Python code

Comment: Agree on @vishakha-mishra comment. You'll need some server side technology to do that. As you want to run a python script, I'd suggest using some python web framework.

Comment: flask is the simplest https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/

Answer (score 1):

One option (as suggested by furas) is to use a python framework (Django, Flask, Bottle) on the backend to create an API server. You could equally do this in node with a call to `require('child_process').exec()`

The other older method is to configure FastCGI on your webserver, which can automatically turn your python file into a url. Here are some stackoverflow answers for that method:

- [Running python through fastCGI for nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048057/running-python-through-fastcgi-for-nginx)
- https://superuser.com/questions/1414728/how-to-run-python-script-via-nginx