# VERY simple HTTP Server on Pi

Tags: python, html, web

I'm still new to Pi And Python - so forgive what might be a silly question.
I need to set up a very simple HTTP Server - that can be accessed from the internet. I don't need the complexity of Apache or anything like that.

After much reading - so far I can use `python -m http.server --cgi`which will let me run a python program from the web. Great.

The problem is this is slow as the program has to load, do what it does, and then send it.
I have found other examples that wrap http.server within the python program - but they all say localhost only.

What do I need to do to manage a simple 'GET' request from within python - that can can be accessed from the Pis IP address?

Thanks - fortunately I have plenty of hair to pull out at the moment. :-)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/wsgiref.html#examples

Comment: Even if you only want a very simple HTTP server, my suggestion would be to [set up nginx](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/nginx.md) and [configure it to run Python for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048057/running-python-through-fastcgi-for-nginx).