# why nginx as frontend and apache as backend

Tags: apache, nginx

I have seen several web service architecture, and all of them is nginx in the front and apache in the back, I just wanna know why this?

I know nginx is good at handle high concurrency request and load balancing, I can make peace of the nginx as front thing, but why the backend is apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly some modules that apache has but nginx does not have. Then you would need apache in your stack somewhere, quite fittingly at the backend, just to do the tasks those modules do.

**Edit**
Even if some equivalent modules do exist, the event-driven nature of nginx may also be detrimental in some scenarios; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1038043/567555) for example.